# XCode: Expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

We created an iOS app quite a while ago which works perfectly on the Mac on which it was developed, but which throws up errors when we try to compile it on a different Mac.

In order to transfer it to the second Mac, we simply copied the entire source directory onto a USB stick.  If this is the cause of my issues, then could somebody let me know a better way to transfer projects.

The project has a number of dependencies pulled in through CocoaPods.  The Pods project/target builds correctly on both Macs.

For legacy compatibility reasons both Macs are runnign XCode 5.0.2 and compiling for iOS 6.1.

When trying to build the main project, we get several errors of the type:

•   Expected identifier or '('

•   Unexpected ‘@’ in program

•   Missing context for method declaration

•   Expected method body

This is an example of the compilation errors on one of my header files (note once again that the code is exactly the same as that which is compiles correctly on the other Mac):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DiagnosticViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *diagnosticReadout;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *connectionNameTextBox;  <- Unexpected ‘@’ in  program
-(void) messageReceived:(NSString*)webPublisherMessage;     <- Missing context for method declaration
@end         <-Expected method body
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what’s going on?  I can only assume that there’s something wrong with the build settings or include paths or something, but I’ve checked through all of them and they all appear to be identical on both Macs.

Comment: Check that you have the same Xcode versions, and check whether you are using absolute paths for anything (you shouldn't). A quick check for absolute paths: Duplicate your whole source tree on the first computer and check if the copy builds.

Comment: Paths are not the issue as that is a class declaration using system-provided types.  OP: have you tried a deep clean (Cmd + Opt + Shft + K)?

Comment: The versions of XCode are the same, there are no absolute paths so far as I can see and the deep clean did not resolve the issue

Comment: Try Perform Action:Preprocess on the file to see if if that step corrupts the file.

Comment: I can't do the Perform Action:Preprocess command on the file as it's a .h file and not a .m file.  When I dod the preprocess command on the .m file it completes with no errors.

Comment: Sounds like a dumb question but where is this code? i.e. `.h` file or `.m` file

Comment: Does the preprocessed result "look correct"?

Comment: Is it possible this is being included in a .c file? Or #include instead of #import?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you don't have any white space character before that line. Just set the cursor on the beginning of the @property that is giving you trouble and try pressing the backspace once or twice. See if the error goes away. This is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like that some time ago.

You should clean the project. If still does not work check for any errors related to XCode not able to create/modify/delete files, since you copied the content from the USB you may have files permissions issues. You could set all the files permissions under the project directory to 777 to the user it is running.

The reason, in my opinion, is that the files being compiled differ from the source code you are looking to.